# How to execute psql interactive in its docker container?

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, psql

I want to run a query in Postgres interactive shell. I'm using a docker container for this purpose as follows:

Here is the relevant piece of docker-compose:

```
  db_of_ivms:
    image: postgres:10
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
     - 5432:5432
    container_name: db_of_ivms
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: xxx
      POSTGRES_USER: ivms_usr
      POSTGRES_DB: ivms_db
```

Nevertheless, I'm dealing with this error:

`docker exec -it -u 0 db_of_ivms bash`

```
# psql

psql: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need shell  in with the postgres user

```
docker exec -it -u postgres db_of_ivms bash
```

Now for containers that you dont specify `POSTGRES_USER: ivms_usr`:

```
postgres@d9b097b8db8c:/$ psql
postgres=# \l
                                 List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |  Collate   |   Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+------------+------------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | 
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
(3 rows)
```

If you specify `POSTGRES_USER: ivms_usr` and Database (note psql command arguments):

```
docker exec -it -u postgres db_of_ivms bash
postgres@2cec2435bb83:/$ psql -U ivms_usr -d ivms_db
psql (10.12 (Debian 10.12-1.pgdg90+1))
Type "help" for help.

ivms_db=# \l
                                 List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |  Collate   |   Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+------------+------------+-----------------------
 ivms_db   | ivms_usr | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | 
 postgres  | ivms_usr | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | 
 template0 | ivms_usr | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/ivms_usr          +
           |          |          |            |            | ivms_usr=CTc/ivms_usr
 template1 | ivms_usr | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/ivms_usr          +
           |          |          |            |            | ivms_usr=CTc/ivms_usr
(4 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, the problem still remains: `/$ psql` : `psql: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist`

Comment: could you please  try with ```docker exec -it -u ivms_usr db_of_ivms bash```

Comment: `unable to find user ivms_usr: no matching entries in passwd file`

Answer (score 1):

I use this procedure for example for getting dump:

```
docker exec -it -u 0 <container-name> bash
```

Now, you could enter `psql` commands with root permission:

```
# pg_dump -U <user-name> <db-name> > dump.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found an **alternative** approach through Django shell:

`$ python manage.py shell`

```py
from django.db import connection

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("DELETE FROM django_migrations WHERE app='settings'")
```